# Writing appender.json_console logs for logstash to file

Tags: log4j, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

Currently all appender.json_console logs are written as stdout and logs are written into a docker container json log for logstash.

Is it possible to utiilse the log4j.properties configuration to write the json_console log to a file like other logstash log. Trying to achieve something like below.

> appender.json_console.fileName = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}.log

Current configuration:

```
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = plain_console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n

appender.json_console.type = Console
appender.json_console.name = json_console
appender.json_console.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.json_console.layout.compact = true
appender.json_console.layout.eventEol = true

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = plain_rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %-.10000m%n

appender.json_rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.json_rolling.name = json_rolling
appender.json_rolling.fileName = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}.log
appender.json_rolling.filePattern = ${sys:ls.logs}/logstash-${sys:ls.log.format}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.json_rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.json_rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.json_rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.json_rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.json_rolling.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.json_rolling.layout.compact = true
appender.json_rolling.layout.eventEol = true
```

Comment: Just in case if someone is trying to achieve this, i had to remove the below line from the logstash.conf to achieve this.
stdout { codec => rubydebug }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if someone is trying to achieve the same. The below fixed my issue
Had to comment out the below lines in logstash.conf

```
#        stdout
#        {
#                codec => rubydebug
#        }
```